# html control disappears after ajax postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radpanelbar

I'm generating the `Div`'s dynamically on the `RadPanelBar` using `jquery`. On the page load it works fine. However, if I collapse and expand the `RadPanelBar` the generated `div`s are disappears from it.

This is how I'm registering the script:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GetLayout", "GetLayout('" + j + "');", true);
```

where `j` is a array of parameters to draw `div`.

Could some on please advice on it?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly [OnClientItemClicked](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/panelbar-onclientitemclicked.html) event, and then redraw the content. You would need to have the parameters already saved on the client in order for this to happen.

You could wrap it in a RadAjaxPanel and force a postback, and then add a [ResponseScript](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-control-properties.html) to then execute your GetLayout method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your divs,you are going to need to one of 2 things.
1>Persist them in a hidden control on the client or somewhere back in the server
2> Not refresh the panel when you call the Ajax Manager. 
When you refresh the ajax manager, the panel goes back to start.